# Python3 setuptools bidst_rpm : remove /usr/lib/python3.x/site-packages prefix. Adapt rpm install directory to client machine's python path

Tags: python, python-3.x, fedora, rpm, setuptools

I'm currently trying to create a rpm distribution of a python project I've been working on. I'm using setuptools 25.1.4 on a Fedora 24 and using python3.4.

I can generate my rpm distribution by using :

```
python3 setup.py bdist_rpm
```

And here is a look at my setup.cfg file :

```
    [bdist_rpm]
no-autoreq=1
requires = python3 >= 3.4
    mariadb
    mariadb-server
    mariadb-devel
    mysql-connector-python3
    redhat-rpm-config
    libffi-devel
    libffi
    libxml2
    libxml2-devel
    libxslt-devel
```

This generates a myproject-1.0.0-1.noarch.rpm file in my dist folder. The rpm distribution has been created using python3.4.

I wish to pass on my rpm file from my host machine to my client machine. I achieve that by doing a simple scp command. Once I'm on my client machine I usually do a sequence of :

```
dnf install myproject-1.0.0-1.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh myproject-1.0.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

Which resolves dependency issues and specifies that my package has been installed.
Now my problem comes from where the package is actually installed on my client machine :

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages`
```

This "path" is generated by the following tar file that setup.py creates and uses to build the rpm distribution :

> myproject-1.0.0.linux-x86_64.tar.gz

When I untar it , it creates a folder copying the path from my host machine /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/my-project/...

This is probably due to the fact that I ran setup.py on my host machine using python3.4

My client machine has python3.5 installed on it by default (thank you Fedora 24)

Of course I could solve this problem by simply executing setup.py using python3.5 on my host machine, but that would be a nasty and unsatisfying fix to my problem.

Now how do I customize this part of setuptools. What I wish to achieve is once the client machine tries to install my rpm , it installs my python project package to the right path of the client machine's python path.

The best situation would be to actually remove the /usr/bin/python3.4/site-packages/ prefix and have it replaced with something as simple as /my-project/ and then once I'm on my client machine put /my-project/ in whatever path the client machine's python active interpretor uses.

I know that the prefix issue has already been addressed at : [setuptools: remove lib/python3.5/site-packages prefix from zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333888/setuptools-remove-lib-python3-5-site-packages-prefix-from-zip) but OP's solution does not work for me.

I'm fairly new here so please point out if I didn't supply enough information.

**SOLVED**
I stumbled upon [Override default installation directory for Python bdist Windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354096/override-default-installation-directory-for-python-bdist-windows-installer)

It worked like a charm adding :

```
[install] 
prefix=/
install_lib=/some/lib/path
install_scripts=/some/bin/path
```

to my setup.cfg

Answer (score 0):

When you run `bdist_rpm` it will also create src.rpm. With this file run:

```
mock -r fedora-24-x86_64 myproject.src.rpm
```

It will create fedora-24-x86_64 environment in chroot and build your package there. With correct paths for Fedora 24.

Comment: I had trouble using your method, I did not find the -f option for the mock command. I tried using : mock -r fedora-24-x86_64 myproject.src.rpm. I had an error doing so , at the end telling me something like "python3 not found"

Comment: Yes. -f is typo. Should be -r. I edited my answer. How did you install mock? On Fedora24 it use python3, but it is required by the package, so DNF should install it automatically.